# Where should I ask a question about the Heroes III HD game on an iPad?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about the game Heroes III HD for the iPad. Specifically, how to delete a saved game. In the Windows version, from the Load Games page, you select a saved game and click the Delete key. On the iPad, you don't have a keyboard available unless the application is expecting text input. So, where is the best Stack Exchange site to ask this question?

Answer (score 4):

Questions about digital games go on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)!

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Arqade is for passionate videogamers from all platforms, including consoles, computers, handhelds, and mobile devices. If your question generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing
> - Game mechanics and terminology
> - Plot and characters in games
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities
>
> …then you are in the right place to ask your question!

:D